# how to bind JFX ProgressBar with my link in java

Tags: java, progress-bar, progress

I am trying to make a java program download an app from my server by getting download link from it with this code :

```
private void downloadFile(String link) throws Exception {

URL url = new URL(link);

URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

int max = conn.getContentLength();

pane.setText(pane.getText()+"\n"+"Downloding files...\nUpdate Size : "+(max/1000000)+" Mb");

BufferedOutputStream fOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new 
   File("update.zip")));
byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];

int bytesRead = 0;

int in = 0;

while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {

    in += bytesRead;

    fOut.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
fOut.flush();

fOut.close();

is.close();

pane.setText(pane.getText()+"\nDownload Completed Successfully!");
```

and it is working fine ... I did search about how to bind my progress bar to this download link but I couldnt figure it out .... I would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [Task](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and perform your download in that Task’s [call](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#call%28%29) method:

```
String link = /* ... */;

File downloadsDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Downloads");
downloadsDir.mkdir();

File file = File(downloadsDir, "update.zip");

Task<Void> downloader = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call()
    throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(link);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        long max = conn.getContentLengthLong();

        updateMessage(
            "Downloading files...\nUpdate Size : " + (max/1000000) + " MB");

        try (InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
             BufferedOutputStream fOut = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(file))) {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];

            int bytesRead = 0;
            long in = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                in += bytesRead;
                fOut.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                updateProgress(in, max);
            }
        }

        updateMessage("Download Completed Successfully!");

        return null;
    }
};
```

Notice the use of the inherited methods [updateProgress](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateProgress%28long,long%29) and [updateMessage](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateMessage%28java.lang.String%29).

Then you can simply bind the ProgressBar’s properties to your Task’s properties.

```
progressBar.progressProperty().bind(downloader.progressProperty());
```

And you can even monitor the Task’s message as it changes:

```
downloader.messageProperty().addListener(
    (o, oldMessage, newMessage) -> pane.appendText("\n" + newMessage));
```

You’ll probably want to let the user know if the download fails.  You can do this with the Task’s [onFailed](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#onFailedProperty) property:

```
downloader.setOnFailed(e -> {
    Exception exception = downloader.getException();

    StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
    exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));

    TextArea stackTraceField = new TextArea(stackTrace.toString());
    stackTraceField.setEditable(false);

    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.initOwner(pane.getScene().getWindow());
    alert.setTitle("Download Failure");
    alert.setHeaderText("Download Failed");
    alert.setContextText(
        "Failed to download " + link + ":\n\n" + exception);
    alert.getDialogPane().setExpandableContent(stackTraceField);
    alert.show();
});
```

Task implements `Runnable`, so you can start it by passing it to any standard multithreading class:

```
new Thread(downloader, "Downloading " + link).start();
```

Or:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(downloader);
```

Or:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
executor.submit(downloader);
```

Comment: Thank you dude <3... you are the best